# Convert large JPG to zoomable SWF

Tags: flash, jpeg, swf

I have a largeish JPG (2400x1000) of an organogram. It would be good to be able to convert this JPG into an SWF that could be zoomed with the mousewheel when displayed within a webpage.

Is this possible **for someone with no Flash skills** using free/online tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Magnifying Class for AS3](http://bjornson.inhb.de/?p=9) (maybe useful)
- [Magic Magnify](http://www.magictoolbox.com/magicmagnify/) (Not Free)
- [**Useful** ActionScript Code](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=72499) done by someone in a forum
- There are also [non-closed/non-answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341441/how-to-zoom-in-out-an-jpg-image-with-actionscript) about this.